# passing multiple value to function defined in contextFunction to update context variable in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-context

I am new to CONTEXT-API. I was building an application where I have some data after fetching it from an API. I used a context-API to update data globally. I did it successfully. My next task was to filter data as the user type something in the input field. For that, I created two functional components.

1st functional component contains a search field and 2nd component contains a body where all data will be displayed.

Now I want to filter the data and update the context array accordingly so that every child component will get filtered data. And here I am just confused about how to pass a variable to a function that is defined in the stationProvider.JSX file to update the CONTEXT variable each time the input variable changes. Here I didn't add that function to avoid confusion.

I would love any suggestion.

Link of file [stationProvider.jsx](https://github.com/unknownBalak/radioapp/blob/master/src/component/StationProvider.jsx). and Link from where I want to pass variable is [Search.jsx](https://github.com/unknownBalak/radioapp/blob/master/src/component/Search.jsx). Please help me regarding this.

```
               StationProvider.jsx File

 export const StationContext = createContext();

export const StationProvider = (props) => {
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
main.then((res) => {
  setData([...res]);
     });
   }, []);
return (
  <StationContext.Provider value={data}>{props.children} 
  </StationContext.Provider>
 );
};





           Search.jsx file

   function Search() {
   const [value, setValue] = useState("noFilter");
   const [input, setInput] = useState("");

   return (
        <div className="searchBar">
       <div className="childContainer" ref={floatDiv}>
         <h1>Filter BY: </h1>
       <div className="tagName">
        <label htmlFor="drowpdown"> Select from DrowpDown: </label>
        <select id="dropdown" onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} 
            required>
        <option value="noFilter"> No Filter </option>
        <option value="country">Country </option>
        <option value="state"> State </option>
        <option value="tag">Tag name </option>
        <option value="station">Station Name </option>
      </select>
      <input
        type="text"
        className={value !== "noFilter" ? "active" : ""}
        placeholder="Enter value name"
        onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
    <h3 style={{ color: "black" }}>
      <span className="warning"> Note: </span> Working on filtering{" "}
       </h3>
     </div>
   </div>
 );
 }
  export default Search;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant code itself, not just a link to it.

Comment: @Bergi, updated. Please guide me.